# Trouble trying to unmount ftp connection in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I can't unmount an ftp connection in my ubuntu by clicking on the unmount option in the GUI.

The only solution that works for me is restarting the machine.

Is there a command or some other trick that will help?

Comment: You probably mean disconnect instead of unmount. What FTP client program are you using exactly?

Comment: @Specur: Most likely it's GNOME's Gvfs, which presents network connections as filesystems.

Comment: @Specur: I'm using Nautilus

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, sftp connections can get stuck. Use

```
ps aux | grep sftp
```

to find the process ID of the ftp connection. If nothing else helps, I normally kill the process with

```
kill <pid>
```

This should only be done if unmounting as user54114 has mentioned doesn't work correctly as it's not really a clean solution. 
However, I'm using gigolo in Xubuntu and I sometimes have to use this method if the connection can't be closed normally anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'mount' to find out where the remote directory is mounted
Then unmount it using fusermount -u